# quasi-experiment

Tags: experiment-design

I am doing one group pre and post test experiment. My samples will be selected by the hotel managers. So, it is random sampling. My question is, can I do a one group pre and post test experiment with this sampling technique?

Answer (score 4):

> My samples will be selected by the hotel managers.

Then this is a convenience sample, and testing will be difficult. How do you know the managers of different hotels take their samples the same way? If you know anything more about how they did the samplin, tell us.